# MEAN Stack how does routing between express and angular work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm using express static to point to public directory

```
//app.js
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/public'));
```

how can I have it so most of the routing for UI is from AngularJS, as of now, it does not work unless on app.js I specify something like this

```
//app.js
app.get('/submit', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/submit.html');
}); 

app.get('/schedule', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/schedule.html');
});
```

if I remove the above part, and create /public/app.js instead, it does not work

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', ['page-ctrl']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: LoginController
      }).
      when('/submit', {
        templateUrl: 'submit.html',
        controller: AddPostCtrl
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

Simply said, what I need is to point to index.html on express, and afterward routing should be done by angular, that way I can do checking on login authentication and reroute to index page, if user not login and try to access other page.

this is what I have for app.js (express) --> /project/app.js

```
/*app.js*/

//dependencies
var fs          = require('fs');
var http        = require('http');
var https       = require('https');
var express     = require('express');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

//variables
var db;
if(process.env.ENV == 'Test')
    db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/videoRequestAPI_Test');
else
    db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/videoRequestAPI');

var app                     = express();
var port                    = process.env.PORT || 13337;
var debug                   = process.env.DEBUG || false;

/**/app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/public'));/**/
/**/app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));/**/       
/**/app.use(bodyParser.json());             /**/    

// route middleware that will happen on every request
var routes = require('./routes');
//app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});


var httpServer              = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(80);

console.log("Server Running! Ports 80 open for traffic");
```

and this is the index.html --> myproject/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="page-ctrl">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/abc.css">

        <script src="js/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-0.13.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>       

        <script src="js/controllers/pageController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>

        <script src="js/services/services.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" >
            <aside class="col-sm-7" text-align="center">
                <img src="img/sd.png" class="logo">
            </aside>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-btn"><a href="/submit">Submit Content</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-btn"><a href="/schedule">Scheduled Content</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-btn active"><a href="/requests">Pending Content</a></li>
                    </ul>           
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="LoginController">
            <input ng-model="email" type="email" class="form-control limit" placeholder="Email">
            <input ng-model="credentials" type="password" class="form-control limit" placeholder="Credentials">
            <button ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-primary btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Login</button>
        </div>
</div>  

        <footer class="footer">
            &copy; (June 2015)
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you are "rerouting" to "index.html" when going to the "/" route. Once you enter the application, you are already on the index.html page. Inside your index.html page you should have an element <div ng-view></div> where the templates that are rendered by your routes will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

In your router.js to do all your API routes first, then a wildcard route for Angular, like this:

```
//API routes first
app.get('/API/users', UserController.getUsers);
app.get('/API/user/:id', UserController.getUserById);


//Then let Angular handle the rest of the routes
app.get('*', function(req,res){
   return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

The index.html being the starting point of your Angular application.

One more thing, make sure the index.html has the following in the "head" tag:

```
<base href="/">
```

EDIT:
A good starting point is to check out this great example:
https://github.com/scotch-io/starter-node-angular

and structure your application the same way:

Comment: in this case, since you use app.get('*'), does not it mean that any url you enter, it will lead to index.html? then how can I go to any other url?

Comment: Once you get to index.html, the Angular routing kicks in

Comment: @Harts Routes are resolved in order. So if you enter a route that has no other routing, it will redirect to the index and then be subject to angular.

Comment: I just tried it, it does not work. Do I need to add app.js (angular one) in app.js on server(express)?

Comment: Is your angular application in the /public folder?

Comment: @Nahn oh that's typo in stackoverflow, on the original one it is correct. but it still not working

Comment: no error, it basicly always go to index.html, no matter which link I click

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a `routes` and `api` folder.

- Each folder contains bunch of request handler functions (req, res, next). Ordered in different files based on the resource or function they serve.
- Each folder has a main file (routes.js / api.js in my case) which maps all functions to the appropriate url / HTTP method. And also invokes authentication on those routes.
- This allows you to very easily use different auth methods for API routes and normal routes.
- If someone requires for instance a missing static asset or and undefined route, and 404 handler is invoked. So that the pages does not return the index page on all requests.

For example routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
        // Authenticate....
    }

    function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {
        // Check for admin
    }

    // Resource puppies
    app.all('/puppies*', ensureAuthenticated)

    // Series (File Upload & Conversion)
    app.get('/puppies', require('./puppie').someRoute)

    // Admin*
    app.all('/admin*', ensureAuthenticated, ensureAdmin)

    // Admin > User
    app.get('/admin/users', require('./admin').find)

    app.all('/', ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, require('./index').index)

    // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
  app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets|views)/*')
   .get(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Resource not found: ' + req.url)
        res.status(404).send(err)
        })

    // Index
    app.all('/*', require('./index').index)
}
```

In app.js you can then use these routes like so

```
require('./routes/routes')(app)
```